# Proof of uniformly integrable martingale converge

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

Martingale Convergence Theorem:

**Def:** $X_n$ a martingale. If $\sup E(X_n^+)<\infty$ then $\exists X_\infty$
$$X_n\rightarrow X_\infty\text{ a.s. and $L^1$}$$

**Def:** Uniformly integrable $\forall\epsilon$ $\exists N$ $\forall M\ge N$
$$E(\mathbb{1}_{(|X_n|\ge M)}|X_n|)<\epsilon$$

Claim uniform integrable martingale satisfy Martingale Convergence Theorem so that the martingale converges. For $M$ large enough:

$$E(X_n^+)\le E(|X_n|)=E(|X_n|\mathbb{1}_{(|X_n|\ge M)})+E(|X_n|\mathbb{1}_{(|X_n|<M)})<\epsilon+E(|X_n|\mathbb{1}_{(|X_n|<M)})$$

How should I continue?

Answer (score 2):

You are basically done.. The only ingredient missing is that $|X_n| < M$ on the event $\{ |X_n|  < M\}$. This is of course trivially true, but leads to:

$$ E(|X_n|\mathbb{1}_{(|X_n|<M)}) \leq E(M\mathbb{1}_{(|X_n|<M)}) \leq M$$

Hence combining with your previous result:

$$ E(X_n^+)\leq E(|X_n|) \leq \epsilon + M$$

Thus:

$$ \sup_n E(X_n^+) \leq \epsilon + M < \infty $$